Openssl, how to avoid the request and instruct command to take from configuration file?
Creating a certificate request I use this line
openssl req -config ssl.config -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout `hostname`.key -out `hostname`.req

in "ssl.config" I put the province, state, mail..etc
the syntax is correct.
But when I create the certificate/key it ask for province, etc..
Is possible to made it non-interactive?
I know this flag
-subj "/C=IT/ST=STATE/L=Location/O=Organization/CN=`hostname`"

but I want the command read it from ssl.config and don't ask..is possible?

Point your config's [req] distinguished_name= to a section with each field specified separately, but also set [req] prompt=no:
[req]
distinguished_name = req_dn
prompt = no

[req_dn]
# Must be in OpenSSL order (reverse of RFC 2223 order), i.e. /C/ST/L/O/CN
countryName = IT
organizationName = Some org
commonName = foo.example.com


I needed to adjust a script I had, making it totally automated/non-interactive by adjusting config.ssl:

Editing some voices (CA private key locations, certs location, etc.)
Using the correct pass-in, pass-out, and batch options 

This script is only an example I use to create self-signed certificates for testing, with the important thing being the use of correct options to avoid interactive mode:
set -e

DOMAIN=blu.priv
HOSTNAME=`hostname`

openssl req -new -config ssl.config -newkey rsa:4096 -days 3650 -x509 -nodes -keyout demoCA/$DOMAIN.key -out demoCA/$DOMAIN.crt -batch

openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout file:passphrase.txt -out demoCA/private/$DOMAIN.key 4096

openssl req -new -config ssl.config -x509 -days 3650 -key demoCA/private/$DOMAIN.key -passin file:passphrase.txt -keyout demoCA/$DOMAIN.key -out demoCA/$DOMAIN.crt -batch

openssl req -config ssl.config -passout file:passphrase.txt -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout $HOSTNAME.key -out $HOSTNAME.req -batch

yes|openssl ca -config ssl.config -passin file:passphrase.txt -out $HOSTNAME.crt -infiles $HOSTNAME.req 

for i in *key;do openssl rsa -passin file:passphrase.txt -in $i -out $i;done


Is config.ssl the standardized openssl config file? Isn't it openssl.conf, or has it been updated to be config.ssl?

i copy it from /etc/ssl/ and then adjust it (name of country, location, organization, etc..)

Right, but isn't the filename itself openssl.cnf||openssl.conf?

Yes but I need a "personal" file, just to not modify system config file.

The reason I ask is in questions and answers it's more helpful to use standardized file names, otherwise it leaves things open to interpretation as to what exactly is config.ssl. In general, the system-wide openssl.cnf is edited and used with the standard expected filename (also, many text editors will have no idea how to syntax highlight a config file with extension .ssl since it's not a valid extension). For a non-Windows OS, editing the system config should prevent having to specify -config
